# How to use a numpy-based external library function within a Tensorflow 2/keras custom layer?

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network, pytorch, tensorflow2.0, keras-layer

I would be very grateful if someone would help me understanding the following problem.

I am trying to implement a custom layer in tensorflow 2 by using keras (it's a layer derived from the class Layer).

I have overriden the build and the call functions.

When I write my call function I need to invoke a method from an external library which only accepts numpy array. It's a pretty complex function and of course it does not use tensorflow functions.
My call function takes in input a tensor, convert it to numpy (by .numpy() function), invoke the external method from another library, then converts the numpy array back to tensor.

Here I have some issues and tried different solutions.

1. If I run the code it tells me that ...ops.Tensor has no method .numpy(). If I correctly understood, this is due to the type of tensor I receive in input to the call function and I need to use the eager mode.
2. If I compile by setting the run_eagerly flag to true, during the fit, it tells me that the gradient is missing. I was hoping that some form of auto-grad computation was implemented but maybe this is not what it is currently happening?.

**Source code:**

```
class SimpleLayer(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self):
        super(SimpleLayer, self).__init__()

    def build(self, input_shape):
        shape_a = input_shape[0]                #batch_size
        shape_b = int(input_shape[1])           #height
        shape_c = int(input_shape[2])           #width
        shape_d = input_shape[3]                #channel_number
        self.w = self.add_weight(shape=(shape_d*shape_a, 2, shape_b, shape_c),
                                 initializer='random_uniform', dtype='float64',
                                 trainable=True)


    def call(self, inputs):
        tf_inputs = inputs.numpy()
        sft = tr.transform(tf_inputs) # call to the external library
        transformed = tf.math.multiply(sft, self.w)
        conv = tf.zeros(np.shape(inputs))
        conv = tr.inv_transform(inputs, transformed) # another call to a function that also converts to tensor
        return conv. # this is a tensor!


.....

model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    layers.experimental.preprocessing.Rescaling(1./255),
    pl.SimpleLayer(),
    layers.Activation('relu'),
    layers.MaxPooling2D(),
    pl.SimpleLayer(),
    layers.Activation('relu'),
    layers.Flatten(),
    layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
    layers.Dense(num_classes)
])

model.compile(
    optimizer='adam',
    loss=tf.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
    run_eagerly=True,  # adding this to avoid graph building
    metrics=['accuracy'])

history = model.fit(train_images, train_labels, epochs=3, batch_size=20,
                    validation_data=(test_images, test_labels))
```

Is there any workaround for that? Can I only use tensorflow 2 functions to process the tensor or maybe I am missing something?

I am also considering to switch to pyTorch (which I do not know yet) but I fear to have the same issue. What would you suggest?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Gradient cannot flow through `numpy` functions as... `numpy` has no autograd capabilities of any sort.

Your custom function will not work in either `tensorflow2.x` nor in `pytorch` as the operation on `numpy` arrays are not recorded.

For your `call` code (in PyTorch it would be `forward`, otherwise really similar), see comments:

```
def call(self, inputs):
    tf_inputs = inputs.numpy() # gradient breaks
    sft = tr.transform(tf_inputs) # still numpy
    transformed = tf.math.multiply(sft, self.w)
    conv = tf.zeros(np.shape(inputs))
    conv = tr.inv_transform(inputs, transformed)
    return conv # Tensor with no gradient history
```

And this would happen for all your `SimpleLayer` layers.

### Possible solutions

- Code those operations in differentiable manner (assuming they are differentiable and do not use operations like `argmax`) either in `tensorflow` or `pytorch` (the latter is easier and more intuitive and you would have easier time with it IMO).
- If your complicated functions use `numpy` and are differentiable then you could code it with PyTorch by rewriting `np.op` to `torch.op` as their APIs are pretty similar and interoperate almost seamlessly
- You may go with [JAX](https://github.com/google/jax) instead of `tf` and `pytorch` as "JAX can automatically differentiate native Python and NumPy functions". Depending on your application it might be worth a shot

Answer (score 0):

```
from tensorflow.python.ops.numpy_ops import np_config
np_config.enable_numpy_behavior()
```

Comment: Please explain your solution. Answers which do not have an explanation and are only code get flagged as low effort.